# Google drive and confidential files

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been looking for quite some time and cannot seem to find the answer I need. I tried using the iframe tag method for Google Docs Viewer to view my files and noticed that pptx, xlsx, etc... PDF seems to be the only one that is visible. So I came to the conclusion I have to use Google Drive and it's API. If that is so, my question is... Can I keep these files hosted on my clients server and use the API to view the files or do they have to be hosted on Google Drive's cloud server? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, sorry. All files are stored on the Google Drive cloud servers.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll have to see if I can work with that or not.